# UITableViewCell's detailTextLabel not use all the available space

Tags: ios, uitableview, detailtextlabel

[image: As shown in the screenshot]

As shown in the screenshot. Just wondering how can I ask the detailTextLabel to make use all of the available space, say, the area of the red rect. I tried to set the frame of the detailTextLabel to make the width bigger which just doesn't work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you create your cell? Using storyboard or programmatically?

Comment: Programmatically, use the UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you to subclass a `UITableViewCell` and put all your cell customization in it. It could look similar to this code:

`CustomCell.h`

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

- (id)initWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier;

@end
```

`CustomCell.m`

```
#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell

- (id)initWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self)
    {
        // Customization not related to positions and sizes of subviews. For example:
        self.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        self.detailTextLabel.text = @"Aaaaaa…";
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // Customization related to positions and sizes of subviews. For example:
    self.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 240.0, 40.0);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try with style `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`

```
YourViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[YourViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. but with the UITableViewCellStyleDefault style, the detail label even doesn't display.